# JavaScript to set SharePoint Task Assign To

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am done beating my head against the wall on this. I have tried MS code, Code from here 
[Set "Assigned To" on SharePoint task using Javascript object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755618/set-assigned-to-on-sharepoint-task-using-javascript-object-model)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/2d9775ad-459c-46bc-989b-5d04d40a2f2f/javascript-how-to-reset-task-list-assigned-to-peoplepicker-field?forum=sharepointdevelopment

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137252/add-task-to-tasks-list-through-javascript-in-sharepoint-2013

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx

and other sites.

I have 100% working code that creates a new task on my sharepoint. The only issue is I simply cannot seem to set the Assigned To field.

Here is what I have...

```
// Start creating of new Tasks

    function createListItem(siteUrl) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tasks');

        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
        //oListItem.set_item('AssignedTo', "SID");
        oListItem.update();

        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededCreate), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedCreate)
        );
    }

    function onQuerySucceededCreate() {
        alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
        retrieveListItems(site);
    }

    function onQueryFailedCreate(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
    createListItem(site);
    //End Create Task
```

I rolled everything back to this point that works to simply create the task without the Assigned To. so everything I have tried is listed in the above links. I am totally stumped as at one point it assigned the task but to some random person in the company, not a good thing.

Comment: What do you know about the user to whom you want to assign the task? For example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38758635/2701677) is great, but only if you happen to know the ID of the user's corresponding item in the current site collection's user information list, which is pretty esoteric if you ask me. You might instead be better off invoking `ensureUser` to get a reference to the user from valid alias, as in [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/197497/38950).

Comment: Maybe problem in user code? You need to use sharepoint user id, then you can create `new SP.FieldUserValue()` and set it to AssignedTo field.

Comment: If I create an entry manually we put in the Assign To field a standard ID and this looks up our name. I tried adding the standard without selecting the looked up name that pops up and it filled in the same as if I selected it. So I am assuming there is some lookup item. I tried matching it to a task with no assigned to and the code I tried gave me a random person. Let me look through Thriggles links as Dmitiri's told me nothing I have not already tried and of which was code that resulted in the wrong person being assigned the task.

Answer (score 0):

First use the `web.ensureUser()` function to get a reference to a user object. `ensureUser()` accepts an alias for a user, such as their login name or email address (other alias fields can be defined in the SharePoint user profile service).

You can then get the `id` property of the user and use that to set the lookup value of your people picker field.

Below is an example that demonstrates how you could accomplish this:

```
(function(siteUrl){

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

    getUser("contoso/JIMBO", // any valid user alias
        assignTask, // function to call on success
        alert // function to call on error
     );

    function getUser(username, onSuccess, onError){
        var user = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(username);
        clientContext.load(user);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function(){
                onSuccess(user);
            },
            function(sender, args){ onError(args.get_message()); }
        );
    }

    function assignTask(user){
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tasks');
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
        var assignedToValue = new SP.FieldUserValue();
        assignedToValue.set_lookupId(user.get_id());
        oListItem.set_item('AssignedTo',assignedToValue);
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function(){
                onQuerySucceededCreate(oListItem);
            },
            function(sender, args){ 
                alert(args.get_message()); 
            }
        );
    }

    function onQuerySucceededCreate(oListItem) {
        alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
        //retrieveListItems(site);
    }

})("http://contoso.com"); // site URL
```