# How do I delegate / reassign a task with javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, task, sharepoint-2013

I have developed a javascript functionality to approve tasks. To do this I have used the following code:

```
    listitem.set_item('Completed',true);
    listitem.set_item('PercentComplete',1);
    listitem.set_item('Status','Completed');
    listitem.set_item('FormData','Approved');
    listitem.set_item('WorkflowOutcome','Approved');
    listitem.update();
```

What I do is run that code for a task list and a specific task. I need to do the same but to reassign the task.

Is there any way to do this in javascript? 
What attributes and what values ​​should I configure for the task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the "Assigned To" field with required value.

```
      var assignedToVal = new SP.FieldUserValue();
        assignedToVal.set_lookupId(1);   //specify User Id 
//Or use below code if you dont know users ID
//      assignedToVal = new SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("UserName"); //or use Domain\LoginID
        listitem.set_item('AssignedTo',assignedToVal );
        listitem.update();
```

Refer the below link for detailed explanation of how to update user field.

[Set "Assigned To" on SharePoint task using Javascript object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755618/set-assigned-to-on-sharepoint-task-using-javascript-object-model)

Comment: The problem is that I want to assign it to a specific user. 
How do I get the id of a specific user?

Comment: if you dont know the ID you can use following code
var assignedToVal = new SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(UserName); //or Domain\userID

Comment: It works. Update user assigned to task. The problem is that it does not update the workflow history. When you delegate a task through the reassign task button, The original task is registered and another task is created with the new assigned user. 
In the task approve functionality that I developed when updating these parameters, the workflow detects and updates its history and generates the new task automatically.
I need to replicate the functionality of the reassign task button, what parameters should I update?

Comment: Can you check which content type is used for that item.